# Connection refused: connect while parsing xml with groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have the following xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE sqlMap PUBLIC "-//ibatis.apache.org//DTD SQL Map 2.0//EN"
    "http://ibatis.apache.org/dtd/sql-map-2.dtd">
 <sqlMap namespace="reports">

   <typeAlias alias="Header" type="VerificationVO"/>
  </sqlMap>
```

While trying to parse this xml using:

```
def sqlMapOld = new XmlParser().parse(file)
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: Connection refused: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This error goes away if I remove the DOCTYPE from the xml snippet.  Is there a way to stop groovy script from trying to connect to the URL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using an appropriate parser, try the `load-external-dtd` feature.

```
def parser= new XmlParser()
parser.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)
def sqlMapOld= parser.parse(new FileInputStream(file))
```

Otherwise I think you'd have to [set](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/XmlParser.html#setEntityResolver%28org.xml.sax.EntityResolver%29) an [EntityResolver](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html?is-external=true) that does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The parser is attempting to download the external DTD referenced in the DOCTYPE.

You have two options, disable the use of the external DTD or set up your Java/Groovy XML environment to use a local catalog of DTDs.

You can disable the external DTD loading with

```
def p = new XmlParser()
p.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)
p.parse(file)
```

For information on setting up and using a local catalog see:
http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/WriteCatalog.html

http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/UseCatalog.html

Answer (score 1):

Try

def sqlMapOld = new XmlParser(false, true).parse(file)

to make it non-validating